# Getting the application's enabled disabled event while opening a pop up

Tags: apache-flex

In my flex application I have several pop ups, when a pop up is opened the application is disabled and enabled back when the pop up is closed.

Is there way to get application's enabled / disabled event and perform some activity like hiding a display object.

I know, I can get open and close event of the pop up but I don't want to write it for all the pop ups and pay for maintainability.

PS: I am using PopUpManager to create pop ups.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You enable/disable the whole application?  Why not just use the 'modal' flag in your popup?

And what are you trying to accomplish?  Just have a component disappear altogether when the popup is visible?  There's several ways of doing that either through setting the visible flag manually, using events, or even binding on a specific boolean flag.

Comment: +1 for using the `modal` flag. For example, `PopUpManager.addPopUp(myPopUp, this, true)`.

Comment: By enable / disable I meant you get that blur effect when you open a pop up or alert box. And I know you can make the component visible / invisible but I need to trap that event when the application becomes blur (On opening a pop up / alert box) to hide the component and show it when the blur effect from the application is removed (On closing a pop up / alert box).